# replacing a value in column datas dynamically? Not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the column Attribute_Label_Name  by Updated_Attribute_Label_Name, but is Updated_Attribute_Label_Name is null then value should be of Attribute_Label_Name

[Click to see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwSm5.png)

```
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #temp
        )
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    Attribute_Label_Name VARCHAR(1000)
    ,Updated_Attribute_Label_Name VARCHAR(1000)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT Attribute_Label_Name
    ,Updated_Attribute_Label_Name
FROM Attribute_Label_With_Sku$

DECLARE @Attribute_Label_Name VARCHAR(1000)
    ,@Updated_Attribute_Label_Name VARCHAR(1000)

SET @Attribute_Label_Name = Attribute_Label_Name
    ,
SET @Updated_Attribute_Label_Name = Updated_Attribute_Label_Name

IF (@Updated_Attribute_Label_Name IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE #temp
    SET @Attribute_Label_Name = @Updated_Attribute_Label_Name
END
ELSE
    (
            SELECT @Updated_Attribute_Label_Name = Updated_Attribute_Label_Name
            )

SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here. That looks like some very "procedural" logic where you're splitting everything out into lots of little steps. SQL excels at set-based logic where you construct a query that describes *what to do*, not *how to do it*, and then the database engine works out the steps. I'm not sure if your entire piece of logic can just be replaced by using [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are not setting this values

```
SET @Attribute_Label_Name = Attribute_Label_Name
    ,
SET @Updated_Attribute_Label_Name = Updated_Attribute_Label_Name
```

you can do in a single select too

```
       select @Attribute_Label_Name =Attribute_Label_Name,
               @Updated_Attribute_Label_Name = Updated_Attribute_Label_Name
        from #temp
```

Further please note,if you get mutiple values from #temp ,you may not get expected results

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Attribute_Label_Name=COALESCE(Updated_Attribute_Label_Name,Attribute_Label_Name)
```

The `COALESCE` function will check the value first in `Updated_Attribute_Label_Name` if it is null, then it will update the same value from `Attribute_Label_Name`.